# Use multiple OUs via Get-Mailbox

Tags: powershell

I have this Powershell code that grabs the mailbox permissions from one OrganisationalUnit. it works very well for single OU. But I want to run multiple OUs.

How can I do that ?

e.g

```
"OU=gmsa_accounts,DC=contoso,DC=local"
"OU=svc_accounts,DC=contoso,DC=local"
"OU=adm_accounts,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=local"
```

Script:

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU=gmsa_accounts,DC=contoso,DC=local"
# creating a table to combine information
$MailboxesResult = @()

# processing all the mailboxes
ForEach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes){
    # getting manager
    $permissions = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox.Alias | ? { ($_.IsInherited -eq $False) -and -not ($_.User -Like "NT AUTHORITY*") }
    $fullAccess = $permissions | Where-Object { $permissions.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" }
    $permissions = Get-RecipientPermission -Identity $mailbox.Alias | ? { ($_.IsInherited -eq $False) -and -not ($_.Trustee -Like "NT AUTHORITY*") }
    $SendAs = $permissions | Where-Object { $permissions.AccessRights -eq "SendAs" }

    # combine eveything in a PSCustomObject
    $item = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name                          = $mailbox.DisplayName
        FullAccess                    = $fullAccess.User -replace '^.+\\' -join ','
        SendAs                        = $($sendas.Trustee) -join (",")
    }
    $MailboxesResult += $item
}
#Export collected information to CSV
$MailboxesResult | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Temp\MailboxFolderPermissions2.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option (depending on how many OU's you have) would be to simply assign each of the OUs you want to query into an array, then loop through that getting each of the results, with the final `Export-CSV` after the loop has completed. For instance :

```
$allOUs="OU=gmsa_accounts,DC=contoso,DC=local",
"OU=svc_accounts,DC=contoso,DC=local",
"OU=adm_accounts,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=local"

# creating a table to combine information
$MailboxesResult = @()
foreach ($OU in $allOUs)
{
    $Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU

    # processing all the mailboxes in the current OU
    ForEach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes){
        # getting manager
        $permissions = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox.Alias | ? { ($_.IsInherited -eq $False) -and -not ($_.User -Like "NT AUTHORITY*") }
        $fullAccess = $permissions | Where-Object { $permissions.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" }
        $permissions = Get-RecipientPermission -Identity $mailbox.Alias | ? { ($_.IsInherited -eq $False) -and -not ($_.Trustee -Like "NT AUTHORITY*") }
        $SendAs = $permissions | Where-Object { $permissions.AccessRights -eq "SendAs" }

        # combine eveything in a PSCustomObject
        $item = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name                          = $mailbox.DisplayName
            FullAccess                    = $fullAccess.User -replace '^.+\\' -join ','
            SendAs                        = $($sendas.Trustee) -join (",")
        }
        $MailboxesResult += $item
    }
}
#Export collected information to CSV
$MailboxesResult | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Temp\MailboxFolderPermissions2.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

With a larger number of OUs I'd perhaps look at retrieving the list of OUs programmatically, but it really depends on your setup for what would/wouldn't work. So for instance if all the OUs you want are in `<name>_accounts` then you could try something like

```
$allOUs=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*_accounts"' -SearchBase 'DC=contoso,DC=local' | Select DistinguishedName
```

and use that at the start rather than the hard coded array.